# Scrapy spider:statistics issue

Tags: logging, scrapy

While running scrapy spider on scrapyd server i am getting one hour time difference between start_time and finish_time.
Ex:
My spider run time is 9 min but scrapy statistics show as 1 hr 9 min
[image]

Please anyone help me to fix this issue...

[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in the screenshot. Scrapy starts around 20:09:35 and ends at 21:19:12, as can be seen from log timestamps. Where do you see the error?

Comment: Is it one-time or periodic issue?

Comment: I am getting 1 hr time difference for all spiders.I have  running scrapy spiders on AWS machine.